# In a SIP INVITE Method Getting 200 Response continuosly

Tags: sip

In an INVITE Request callee is sending me a 200(OK) response, I am sending an ACK but now I don't know if the callee is not receiving the acknowledgement or not because I am still receiving the 200 response continuously Below is the Request and Response.

Here is the Entire SIP dialog:

```
INVITE sip:3000@192.168.1.101 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bKe446822249352251a5bd13b6e66ef303;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Contact: <sip:3001@192.168.1.9:5070>
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL
User-Agent: MySIP V2.0
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 179
<------------->


<--- Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.1.9:5070 --->
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP  192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bKe446822249352251a5bd13b6e66ef303;received=192.168.1.9;rport=5070
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="50310a1a"
Content-Length: 0



 <--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.1.9:5070 --->
ACK sip:3000@192.168.1.101 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP   192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bKe446822249352251a5bd13b6e66ef303;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 1 ACK
User-Agent: MySIP V2.0
Content-Length: 0

<------------->


<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.1.9:5070 --->
INVITE sip:3000@192.168.1.101 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bK4fc5c00de7440b65f8b5355cfacb82d2;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Contact: <sip:3001@192.168.1.9:5070>
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL
User-Agent: MySIP V2.0
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 179
Authorization: Digest username="3001", realm="asterisk", nonce="50310a1a",  opaque="", uri="sip:3001@192.168.1.101:5060", response="b1e38ea10061a0224e2189e9177fff1c", algorithm=MD5
<------------->


<--- Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.1.9:5070 --->
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bK4fc5c00de7440b65f8b5355cfacb82d2;received=192.168.1.9;rport=5070
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:3000@192.168.1.101:5060>
Content-Length: 0
<------------>


<--- Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.1.9:5070 --->
SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bK4fc5c00de7440b65f8b5355cfacb82d2;received=192.168.1.9;rport=5070
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:3000@192.168.1.101:5060>
Content-Length: 0
<------------>

<--- Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 192.168.1.9:5070 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bK4fc5c00de7440b65f8b5355cfacb82d2;received=192.168.1.9;rport=5070
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:3000@192.168.1.101:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 195
<------------>


<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.1.9:5070 --->
ACK sip:3000@192.168.1.101:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bKd8c26ff688480593ce616e913ac8e609;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 2 ACK
Authorization: Digest username="3001", realm="asterisk", nonce="50310a1a", opaque="", uri="sip:3001@192.168.1.101:5060", response="b1e38ea10061a0224e2189e9177fff1c", algorithm=MD5
User-Agent: MySIP V2.0
Content-Length: 0
<------------->


Retransmitting #1 (no NAT) to 192.168.1.9:5070:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bK4fc5c00de7440b65f8b5355cfacb82d2;received=192.168.1.9;rport=5070
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:3000@192.168.1.101:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 195
---

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.1.9:5070 --->
ACK sip:3000@192.168.1.101:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP   192.168.1.9:5070;branch=z9hG4bK542e162569381a2bd29c111fa3ea6e03;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: Sahitya<sip:3001@internalmail.com>;tag=m1RbnnhW7m
To: Prithvi<sip:3000@192.168.1.101>;tag=as69cbf848
Call-ID: b6c72c48-402d-40d3-aabf-0538eb1bb630@internalmail.com
CSeq: 2 ACK
Authorization: Digest username="3001", realm="asterisk", nonce="50310a1a", opaque="", uri="sip:3001@192.168.1.101:5060", response="b1e38ea10061a0224e2189e9177fff1c", algorithm=MD5
User-Agent: MySIP V2.0
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: where you capturing it, why i can see via header?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is because on your second INVITE request you are re-using the same Call-ID, From Tag and To Tag as the original INVITE. They should all be different values for the second INVITE request as it's a new transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In the second INVITE:

- the From Tag should be different
- the Via branch should be different
- the To Tag should be missing

Also in the ACK for the 200 OK:

- the From, To, Via and Call-ID should be the same like in the 200 OK

Otherwise there are obvious bugs also in the called party side (such as accepting INVITE with to tag).